# indexOf search in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My code:

```
currentName = "Black";

const bannedItems = [
"Green",
"Yellow",
"Black",
"White"
];
```

When I type this in the console I get False:

```
(currentName.indexOf(bannedItems) != -1);
```

But when I try this I get True:

```
(currentName.indexOf("Black") != -1);
```

So that means I can't use an array for that? This is how I do it now and I thought there's more elegant way

```
if ((currentName.indexOf("Green") != -1 || currentName.indexOf("Yellow") != -1 || currentName.indexOf("Black") != -1 || currentName.indexOf("White") != -1)) return;
```

Comment: and what would you really like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different `indexOf` methods.

```
String.indexOf(substring)
Array.indexOf(array_member)
```

You are using the former. It looks for the string specified in `substring` in the string you are searching.

`"Black"` appears in the string `"Black"`

`"Green,Yellow,Black,White"` (which is what you get when you convert your array to a string) does not appear in the string `"Black"`.

If you want to search for the string `"Black"` in your array, then you need to call the `indexOf` method of **the array**:

```
bannedItems.indexOf(currentName) != -1
```

Comment: But what if currentName was:
var currentName = "Test | Black";

Then it would return False. I want to check if there's a word from bannedItems array in the currentName

Comment: @Alue — Then you need to test (e.g. using `forEach`) each word in the array in turn. `String.indexOf` only accepts a single thing to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap `bannedItems` and `currentName`:

`bannedItems.indexOf(currentName)`

Method `indexOf` is inherent in strings and arrays.

Your `currentName.indexOf("Black")` returns `true` because string "Black" does indeed contain a string "Black".

Answer (score 0):

The proper order of variables:

```
bannedItems.indexOf(currentName) != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a **specified value in a string.**

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

**Note:** The indexOf() method is case sensitive.